# what is the alternative to $stateChangeStart in angular-ui latest version

Tags: angularjs

In [angular-ui.router v1.0.0alpha0](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0alpha0)

All state events, (i.e. $stateChange* and friends) are deprecated and disabled by default;

now what to use in place of that ? without using the ng1/stateEvents.js file. can we use `$transitions.<hooks>`

and how do we access **data** attribute define in .state just to check authentications

```
 $stateProvider
    .state("base", {
        url : "/",
        templateUrl: "base.html",
        controller: 'BaseController'
        data : { pageTitle : 'Base' }
    })
```

earlier we can access by `$state.current.data.pageTitle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to solve this.

Now we need to use [`$transitionsProvider`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/index.html) inside `.config()` not inside `.run`

```
app.config(['$transitionsProvider',function($transitionsProvider) {
$transitionsProvider.onBefore( {to:'base'}, 
    function($transition$, $state) {
         console.log($state.current.data);                
    }
 );
```

})

Hope it helps someone.